# LOAD DATA INFILE with Variable

Tags: mysql, csv

Is there are way to use LOAD DATA INFILE with a variable that contains a CSV.

```
DECLARE _CSV_To_Import VARCHAR(1000);
SET _CSV_To_Import = "test1; test2; test3; test4";

LOAD DATA INFILE _CSV_To_import
INTO TABLE test;
```

If not, what would be the fastest way to do this operation if it's something that would be done multiple times a day with about 1000 items in each list.

Comment: What is your data source?

Comment: Data is coming from user input via textarea

Comment: Why not to generate INSERT statements?

Comment: doing a while loop with INSERT statements takes about 20 seconds each time

Comment: Try to insert several rows at once INSERT INTO table VALUES (...),(...),(...).

Comment: I'll give that a shot, just need to find a way to format the data correctly

Comment: Also, if you go through the table records and insert data to another table, then you could use one INSERT...SELECT statement.

Comment: After using a bulk insert into a single temporary table and then inserting into other tables from the temporary table I was able to get the page load speed from 17 seconds to 4-1/2 seconds